# Как переделать select в input с выпадающим списком

Tags: javascript

Нужен скрипт который заменяет select на инпут с выпадающим списком и с возможностью выбора только одного элемента. Желательно по ID.

```
<select data-placeholder="Выберите категорию ..." name="catlist[]" id="category" onchange="onCategoryChange(this)" style="width:350px;height:140px;" multiple="multiple"><option value="0"></option><option value="12">Эвакуаторы</option><option value="11">Техпомощь на дорогах</option><option value="10">Автомеханика</option><option value="9">Автоэлектрика</option></select>
```

Comment: а чем не устраивает select?

Comment: Необходимо выбрать только одну категорию, а через селект все выбрать можно

Comment: Неправда.......

Answer (score 1):

Убираем из селекта атрибут `multiple="multiple"` и можно выбирать только одну категорию из списка

```html
<select data-placeholder="Выберите категорию ..." name="catlist[]" id="category" onchange="onCategoryChange(this)" style="width:350px;height:140px;">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="12">Эвакуаторы</option>
  <option value="11">Техпомощь на дорогах</option>
  <option value="10">Автомеханика</option>
  <option value="9">Автоэлектрика</option>
</select>
```

Также, скорее всего, надо поменять имя с `catlist[]` на `category`